# simplicial deRham complex and model category structure

Tags: flags, model-categories, simplicial-stuff, differential-graded-algebras, at.algebraic-topology

To every simplicial manifold is associated its simplicial deRham complex.

Is there any literature that discusses explicitly to which extent this classical construction, regarded as a (contravariant) functor from simplicial manifolds to dg-algebras, is homotopical?

For instance: simplicial manifolds naturally embed into the category of simplicial presheaves on the category of manifolds, on which we have the standard local model structure on simplicial presheaves. On dg-algebras there is the standard model structure on dg-algebras.

Is there any literature that discusses explicitly the respect of the simplicial deRham complex operation of the respective weak equivalences?

Comment: Some of this is handled in the nLab, I believe, and there are some references dotted around in the relevant entries.

Comment: This paper: http://front.math.ucdavis.edu/0810.1747 contains a covariant version of simplicial de Rham theory, with good categorical properties.  I wrote it with applications to model structures in mind, although no such applications are actually in the paper.

Comment: Could someone retag this? (I'm not really competent to do it myself.)

Comment: I retagged it, but did not take flags off, maybe I should have.